# Map export to CSV file

Tags: scala, csv, export-to-csv

I have a Map[String,Seq[Any]], and I want to serialize it to a CSV file.

example:

```
Map("k1"-> List(1,2,3),"k2"->List ("toto","fofo","popo"))
```

to

```
k1,k2
1,toto
2,fofo
3,popo
```

any suggestions ??

Comment: if the input was `Map("k1"-> List(1,2,3),"k2"->List ("toto","fofo")) ` what would be the output ?

Comment: the output should be a csv file.

Comment: okay, what would be inside the csv with this input ? `Map("k1"-> List(1,2,3),"k2"->List ("toto","fofo"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this can be a start:

```
val m : Map[String, Seq[Any]] = Map("k1"-> Seq(1,2,3),"k2"->Seq("toto","fofo","popo"))

val file = new File("/path/to/output/file")
val pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file))

val header = m.keys.toList
val numLines = m(header.head).get.size
pw.println(header.mkString(","))

(0 until numLines).foreach(n => {
  val line = header.map(k => m(k)(n)).mkString(",")
  pw.println(line)
})
pw.close()
```

*EDIT*: I had misunderstood the question and the original answer was wrong. For another approach see LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez's [link](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/81ib0x60T1S7E1jkh90nUg/2).

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Unfortuately, I cannot delete this answer since it is accepted. I will edit it with a link to your solution.

Comment: @moezskanjii please check the comments and the edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

To solve this problem, i would define a method like below **if I don't have control on the lists sizes** :

```
def zipNestedLists[A](lists: List[List[A]]): List[List[Any]] = lists match {
    case Nil      => Nil
    case Nil :: _ => Nil
    case _        => lists.map(_.head) :: zipNestedLists(lists.map(_.tail))
  }
```

if I'm sure that all lists have the same size, then in this case i would use `transpose` :

```
scala> List(List(a1,a2,a3,a4), List(b1,b2,b3,b4), List(c1,c2,c3,c4)).transpose
List(List(a1,b1,c1),List(a2,b2,c2),List(a3,b3,c3),List(a4,b4,c4))
```

please see https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#transpose for more infos on `transpose`.

Then construct the header :

```
  val header: String = map.keySet.mkString(",")
```

After that, the body :

```
 val body = zipNestedLists(map.values.toList)
```

then output to the file (thanks @jrook)

```
val file = new File("path") 
val pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file))
pw.println(header)
body.foreach(v => pw.println(v.mkString(",")))
pw.close()
```

Please note that the method `zipNestedLists` will fail for empty lists. Filter non empty lists before calling it.